# How long does an Instance of my appWidget exist

Tags: android-appwidget

**My simple Question:**

How long does an instance of an appwidget exist?

To be more precise.

If I declare a static variable in an appwidget:

```
public static int myInt = 5;
```

Is it all the time accessable from my other activities which only launch if I click on the button?

Or does it just exist at an update which is defined in xml or if I click on the appwidget till the code has been finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static variable exists as long as your process alive.

Comment: and the process of my appWidget is alive as Long as it is on the home Screen right?

Comment: no, an appwidget lives in home screen process, your process is alive as long as Android consider its necessary.

Comment: Ok, and there is no way to force the process open?

Comment: No, for example user can stop it manually or your process will be lost during reboot.